# Why is that, the base of the logarithm is always taken as 2 in finding time complexity of algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

Consider this code,

```
function isPrime(n):
for i from 2 to n - 1:
    if (n mod i) = 0, return false
return true
```

That inner loop runs O(n) times and each time does some amount of work to compute n mod i (as a really conservative upper bound, this can certainly be done in time O(n^3)). Therefore, this overall algorithm runs in time O(n^4) and possibly a lot faster.

Our algorithm runs in time O(n^4), but what is that as a function of the number of input bits? Well, writing out the number n takes O(log n) bits. Therefore, if we let x be the number of bits required to write out the input n, the runtime of this algorithm is actually O(2^(4x)), which is not a polynomial in x.

My question here is

> To write a number n in bits, it must take log n bits(Base 10). Therefore if we let x be the number of bits, then the actual run time must be O(10^(4x)). This is drastically different from O(2^(4x)). How can we afford to do such an approximation??

Comment: Where did you get `10^(4x)` and `2^(4x)`? That would be [superpolynomial time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Superpolynomial_time) not log time complexity.

Comment: "To write a number n in bits, it must take log n bits(Base 10)." No. The number n is about log10(n) digits and log2(n) bits long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conversion between logarithm bases is equivalent to multiplying by some constant.  Constant multiplication does not affect big O complexity class.  So the logarithm base has no effect on the analysis.

However, the example in your question isn't really about logarithms.  It's kind of the opposite, as it's about exponential expressions.  But I don't exactly understand the example because the phrase " it must take log n bits(Base 10)" doesn't make sense to me.  A number n actually has about `log n (base 2)` bits, not base 10, as you assert.

Answer (score 2):

Your function either takes in a base-2 representation of `n`, or a base-10 representation, not both. In the first case, the input size is unambiguously `x = log_2(n)` and in the latter it is inarguably `x = log_10(n)`. If your algorithm takes time proportional to `n^4` (for instance), then the first machine does `O((2^x)^4 = O(2^(4x))` and in the latter it takes `O((10^x)^4) = O(10^(4x))`. Indeed, `10^(4x)` grows asymptotically much faster than `2^(4x)` as can be easily verified.

This isn't typically viewed as a problem since the machine model is assumed to be held constant for a given analysis. It is easy to show that changing the machine model can change lots of things about complexity; for instance, detecting palindromes is known to take linear time in RAM machines and quadratic time in single-tape deterministic Turing machines.

What is more important is consistency within a given model. And, as long as you remain within a given model (a machine is binary or decimal) then there are no worries.

"But wait", you say, "I can be on one machine and pass in strings encoding my input as either binary or decimal!" This is true. However, in this case, the algorithm that takes a base-2 representation and requires O(n) is actually faster (as a function of the input) compared to the decimal one that takes O(n). Why? because `n` is an exponential function of input size in each case and 2 is a smaller base than 10. So it does tell us useful information in this case (but note that we haven't taken any logarithms here, just done exponents).

Really, you are conflating logarithms with exponents since both are involved in analyzing the runtime of your function. Bases of logarithms are interchangeable, but bases of exponents are not.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use arbitrarily big numbers (and thus bignum libraries), integers fit into registers and are elaborated directly by CPU instructions, which take constant time to execute<sup>1</sup> regardless of the number of "on" bits in the input. Thus, the modulo operation in your inner loop is O(1).

On the other hand, if n doesn't *really* have a boundary, of course we can no longer say that mod is O(1).

Now, even if we imagined that the algorithm is polynomial in the number of digits of the number, it doesn't really matter what base you choose: say `mod` is O(d^a) where `d` is the number of decimal digits of `n` (i.e d=log10(n) ); logarithms in different bases differ just by a multiplicative factor, so we have log10(n) = k log2(n), hence O((log10(n))^a) = O(k^a (log2(n))^a) = O((log2(n))^a) because big-oh notation isn't interested in multiplicative constants, so you see that it's really the same.

---

1. that's completely true on simple CPUs, where for each instruction you could say exactly the number of machine cycles; modern CPUs are way more complex and the cost of an individual instruction is more complex to determine, but still it doesn't typically depend on the exact bit pattern of the input.